# Logger.Writer.(*os.File) (non-interface type func() io.Writer on left)

Tags: go, logging

After initializing the logger:

```
var Logger *log.Logger

f, err := os.OpenFile("somefile", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
Logger = log.New(f, "prefix: ", log.LstdFlags)
```

---

I would like to close the destination file of a logger:

```
func main() {
    // Close log writer on exit
    defer func(){
        if file, ok := Logger.Writer.(*os.File); ok {
            file.Sync()
            file.Close()
        } else if handler, ok := Logger.Writer.(io.Closer); ok {
            handler.Close()
        }
    }()

    // ...
}
```

---

But the `Logger.Writer.(*os.File)` syntax gives error:

```
 invalid type assertion: Logger.Writer.(*os.File) (non-interface type func() io.Writer on left)
```

---

How do I close the destination file of a logger?

Answer (score 3):

The error pretty much spells it out for you: [`Logger.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.Writer) is a method on `Logger`, not a field:

```
func (l *Logger) Writer() io.Writer
```

It returns the original `io.Writer` given to [`log.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#New).

You are attempting to convert the **function** `Logger.Writer` to a `*os.File` (and then to a `io.Closer`). Instead, you need to convert the returned value:

```
...
if file, ok := Logger.Writer().(*os.File); ok {
  ...
} else if handler, ok := Logger.Writer().(io.Closer); ok {
...
```